# OpenVPN not with Windows 7 PCs on client Lan

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

I have a setup with a router running OpenWRT with an openvpn client.

Windows 7 pc's cannot access the vpn. They time out trying to access servers on the VPN.
The mystery to me is that the setup works fine for my laptop running ubuntu. I can access the VPN without any issues.

I previously had a router running Tomato with the same openvpn setup and all the computers could access the VPN.

What could account for the difference in behaviour? Is there something I am missing in the OpenWRT setup that is required for windows networking that is on by default with tomato?

To clarify the OpenVPN client is on the OpenWRT router. The client connects to the OpenVPN server. But when I try to access the VPN from Windows computers on my network I cannot.

Comment: Make sure the Windows 7 OpenVPN client is running in administrative mode.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The openvpn client is on the OpenWRT router.

Comment: As Adrian said, you need to supply more details. Is OpenVPN in tun or tap mode? What are the client and server configs?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to supply some information in order to receive a more detailed answer, but it's quite possible that you need to have a NAT set up for forwarding traffic between the wireless network subnet and the OpenVPN subnet.

Also, you must ensure that your server is properly pushing your OpenVPN routing statements upon connection. Turning up your debug logs for this client from your OpenVPN server will aid in this diagnosis once you post them.